# Is the following presentation for $D_8$ a valid presentation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

My professor used the following presentation for $D_8:$

$$D_8 = \{s,t | s^2 = t^2 = (st)^4 = 1\}$$

But I am not sure if this presentation is correct, I looked at subWiki here https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Constructing_dihedral_group:D8_from_its_presentation  but I also could not find this presentation. Can someone tell me if this is really another equivalent presentation for $D_8$ or my professor made a mistake? and how to check that 2 presentations are equivalent.

Comment: The group $D_8$ is a quotient of the group with that presentation, which you can realize by taking $s$ and $sr$ for $s$ and $t$ (where $r$ is the rotation and $s$ is a reflection).  Show that using the relations there are at most 8  distonct elements that can be constructed using $s$ and $t$ to show the presented group has order 8 to conclude they are isomorphic. (e.g., show that $ts=(st)^3$).

Comment: What do you mean by a *quotient*, my understanding is the quotient is a group quotiented (divided) by another group, what is the other group in this case?@ArturoMagidin

Comment: The presentation defines a group $G$. By von Dyck's theorem, given any group $K$ with elements $a$ and $b$ satisfying the relations in the presentation there exists a unique group homomorphism $G\to K$ sending $s$ to $a$ and $t$ to $b$. If $K$ is generated by $a$ and $b$, then the map is surjective, so *necessarily* $K$ is (isomorphic to) a quotient of $G$. The fact that $D_8$ is generated by elements satisfying the relations means that $D_8$ is a quotient of whatever group is determinedby the presentation. These are standard, basic considerations for dealing with presentations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [Arturo Magidin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/742/arturo-magidin) already said in the comments of your question: You can solve this equality by showing both presentations are equal regarding tietze transformations.

The two needed here are adding a generator with a relation and then removing a generator under certain conditions.

Let us first add a generator with a relation for it:
$$
\begin{align}
&\langle s,t \mid s^2, t^2, (st)^4 \rangle \\
= &\langle s,t,u \mid s^2, t^2, (st)^4, u=st \rangle 
\end{align}
$$
(Note: I usually omit the $=1$ part when every relator is $=1$.)

Now we can replace all instances of for example $t$ with the new relator:

$$
\begin{align}
&\langle s,t,u \mid s^2, t^2, (st)^4, u=st \rangle \\
= & \langle s,t,u \mid s^2, (sst)^2, (st)^4, u=st \rangle \\
= & \langle s,t,u \mid s^2, (su)^2, (u)^4, u=st \rangle 
\end{align}
$$
Now because $t$ is in exactly one relation and the relations do not include $t^{-1}$ we can remove it and the relation:

$$
\begin{align}
& \langle s,t,u \mid s^2, (su)^2, (u)^4, u=st \rangle \\
= & \langle s,u \mid s^2, (su)^2, (u)^4 \rangle 
\end{align}
$$

Now we can see that both presentations are equal and the groups they generate are at least isomorphic.

I wanted to give you a good resource to read up on tietze transformations, as I learned it at university with a script I think is not public and the online resources I found did not look that great. If anybody has a recommendation I would be happy.

Answer (score 1):

In the first link you gave is equivalent to the
[ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dihedral_Group/Group_Presentation) version.
This dihedral group presentation is given as
$$ \langle a, b : a^n = b^2 = (ab)^2 = e \rangle. \tag1$$
Compare that to your version
$$ \{s,t | s^2 = t^2 = (st)^4 = 1\}. \tag2$$
Now let
$$ n = 4,\;a = st,\; b=t^{-1}=t,\; ab=s,\; e = 1, \tag3$$
which shows the correspondence between them.

Comment: I still can not see how you get the values of $a,b$ and $c$

Comment: @Secretly I have added a bit more detail. I hope this is more clear.